# Parse CSV options value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a CSV values of list box options in a string, how do I parse value and text separately from it?

Here is my string:

```
[<option value=​"Employee_OID">​Portal EID​</option>​, <option value=​"EmpID">​Emp ID</option>​, <option value=​"Employee_Name">​Name​</option>​]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your whole string, you can remove the outside brackets, then split on the comma to get an array of elements.  You can then turn them into jQuery objects in a loop and get the value/text (You can also do it using regular JS)

```
var data = '[<option value="Employee_OID">Portal EID</option>, <option value="EmpID">Emp ID</option>, <option value="Employee_Name">Name</option>]';​​​​​

data = data.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',');

$.each(data,function(i,v){ // loop through each option
   console.log("Value = " + $(v).val()); // gets option value
   console.log("Text = " + $(v).text()); // gets option text
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/W2dUb/

As @Kevin stated, you can use regex also

```
data = data.replace(/(\[|\])/g,'').split(',');
```

Comment: or `data.replace(/(\[|\])/g,'').split(',')`

Comment: @KevinB ahh.. regex.. my weakness!!  Thanks, I added it to my answer

Comment: I imagine you could also skip the .replace and just remove the first and last parts of the string using basic string manipulation(an area I don't have a lot of experience with).